# after server reboot containers went in restart loop

Tags: docker

I have 8 containers running in a host. When I restarted the host server, 4 out of 8 containers went in a restart loop.

Below operation performed before server reboot:

1. updated restart policy of each container to "always"
2. cpu-sets assigned to each container.

Below are the logs from one sample container (same logs can be seen for rest of 3 containers)

```
Jul 29 19:07:28 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:28.950906638+05:30" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 950a6df
ee89162c0d21911fd4875466af986ee75d49955eb87f989451c2a1cae (28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4)"
Jul 29 19:07:30 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:30+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=3003
Jul 29 19:07:30 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:30+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4
Jul 29 19:07:30 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:30+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=3664
Jul 29 19:07:31 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:31+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4
Jul 29 19:07:31 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:31+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=4075
Jul 29 19:07:31 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:31+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4
Jul 29 19:07:32 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:32+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=4540
Jul 29 19:07:32 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:32+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4
Jul 29 19:07:33 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:33+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=4888
Jul 29 19:07:33 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:33+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4
Jul 29 19:07:34 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:34+05:30" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" add
ress="/containerd-shim/moby/28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4/shim.sock" debug=false pid=5236
Jul 29 19:07:35 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-29T19:07:35+05:30" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b
05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4

Jul 30 11:32:22 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:22.168356749+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:23 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:23.170414772+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:24 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:24.175846696+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:25 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:25.179462074+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:26 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:26.180273919+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:27 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:27.184552211+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:28 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:28.191554766+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:29 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:29.196273850+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:30 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:30.202965670+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:31 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:31.205259453+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:32 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:32.210054931+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:33 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:33.215448730+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:32:34 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:32:34.220660678+05:30" level=error msg="collecting stats for 28cdbceb291cff58e2a799
3b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4: no such container"
Jul 30 11:55:51 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T11:55:51.246346075+05:30" level=error msg="28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc5
4c2a84e124e56638951c4 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Jul 30 12:06:17 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T12:06:17.551094064+05:30" level=error msg="28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc5
4c2a84e124e56638951c4 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Jul 30 12:21:32 docker-worker-3-7 dockerd: time="2020-07-30T12:21:32.309091576+05:30" level=error msg="28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc5
4c2a84e124e56638951c4 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
```

Server restarted at Wed Jul 29 19:06

To avoid an outage, we have recreated the containers **but wanted to know the reason behind this "container restart loop"**

Comment: Can u share an example container AND image information please.

Comment: Hi, container id is 28cdbceb291cff58e2a7993b05c1401464b92743bc54c2a84e124e56638951c4 and image (ausf_auth_v_1_1_3) used is customized image created on UBI7 ,

Comment: Well I dont thing someone can help here. A customized image with a restart problem is more of a debugging thing then reading a logfile, sorry.

Comment: Okay. thanks for the try. when I say the customized image it implies image to build upon standard RHEL UBI 7 with Java app binary. that's it..nothing special.

Comment: added additional logs to the actual post.